# Alter command denied to user

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb

I running spring boot and try to generate database, i have a access problem

Database is created but not foreign key

so i done:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO  'dbuser@localhost';
flush privileges;`
```

launch spring boot application, but get this  error about alter denied to dbuser

```
ALTER command denied to user 'dbuser'@'localhost' for table 'room_payment'
2015-07-16 12:04:28.099 ERROR 4550 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table vehicle add constraint FK_2k13lq037sx9358mhlf9gfmsc foreign key (model_modelId) references model (model_id)
2015-07-16 12:04:28.100 ERROR 4550 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : ALTER command denied to user 'dbuser'@'localhost' for table 'vehicle'
2015-07-16 12:04:28.102  INFO 4550 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong quoting:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO  'dbuser@localhost';
                     ^----------------^
```

Since the whole thing is quoted, that's just a username. You want

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO  'dbuser'@'localhost';
                            ^-^
```

instead. Note the extra quotes.